# Wordpress API not found error

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-json-api

I'm trying to call an API on our web server that allows us to create a user account in a Wordpress site.

If I enter the URL into a browser it works fine. If I try to call it via code it comes up with the following error : -

```
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
```

This is the code that I'm using

```
string URL = "http://api.mywebsite.com/pol-wp/api/user/register/?username=john&email=test@test.comm&nonce=7706960c14&display_name=John&notify=both&user_pass=xxx&insecure=cool";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentLength = 0;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Update: Pasting the URL in Chrome works fine , but pasting it into IE produces the 'Not Found' error message

Comment: Try using [wp_remote_get](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get), I had a similar problem - when pasted in the browser the JSON was showing, but when used CURL, or any other method, nothing. `wp_remote_get()` did the job.